# How to remove unwanted contour from a plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to keep the contour with the black point inside. How can I remove the contour situated on the right side without the black point inside without changing the x and y range?

```
ContourPlot[
 9359.40 + 4764.64 a^4 - 629.36 b + 478.27 b^2 - 11.27 b^3 + 
  3.62 b^4 + a^3 (-22894.13 + 134.51 b) + 
  a^2 (40827.53 - 675.68 b + 274.13 b^2) + 
  a (-32015.56 + 1087.07 b - 707.47 b^2 + 4.30 b^3), {a, 0.85, 
  1.6}, {b, -0.1, 2}, Contours -> {1}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Magenta}, None}, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.011], Point[{1, 1}]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Black}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction`:

```
ContourPlot[
 9359.40 + 4764.64 a^4 - 629.36 b + 478.27 b^2 - 11.27 b^3 + 
  3.62 b^4 + a^3 (-22894.13 + 134.51 b) + 
  a^2 (40827.53 - 675.68 b + 274.13 b^2) + 
  a (-32015.56 + 1087.07 b - 707.47 b^2 + 4.30 b^3), {a, 0.85, 
  1.6}, {b, -0.1, 2}, Contours -> {1}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Magenta}, None}, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.011], Point[{1, 1}]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Black}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, a < 1.2]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi Thank you